Body in a sack hanging above a fire?
I am trying to find movie that I watched when I was younger. The parts that really stick out in my mind are a sack filled with body parts hanging above a fire and I think somebody using a toad or something to poison an arrow. I think it was made in the late 90's to early 00's. Also, I think it was set in the Civil War era. Any help?

I believe the film you're describing is THE MISSING. It's a 2003 film with Tommy Lee Jones in the Civil War / Wild West era setting and a character gets put in a leather skin sack and roasted over a fire.

That's the one thanks.

Might be the right answer, but where's Harvey Keitel (maybe you're mistaking Tommy Lee Jones for him?) and where's the civil war (maybe you're mistaking the wild west for it?)?

@LeviWood Don't forget to accept this answer if it was the correct solution to your problem.

@NapoleonWilson yes youre right , i always get those two actors mixed up ! now edited.
